# What program generates character sprite sheets like this?

Tags: sprites

I see template sprites like this a lot but cant find what program creates them.

**To clarify I am looking for the program or generator that is creating the characters not laying them out.** I've seen the same character as fat, skinny, and short which makes me think its just being generated by a program for reference.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually generated and not just a series of hand-edited pixel art all done by the same guy?

Comment: I doubt a program is creating the sprites themselves. These are most likely created by an artist like [Tetrad](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51/tetrad) suggested.

Comment: @Tetrad yes I'm pretty sure it is just generated to send off to a designer to create the frames you have shown. If you google image... character sprite template, you'll see a lot of similar templates and they all start out with the same pose on each row.

Comment: Why was this marked as duplicated? He was asking for a program that automatically generated characters, not packing them in an atlas.